# After CURL soap response mail is not sending

Tags: php

I have web page that sends a ajax post to a PHP Curl post, the request works but when I request for mail to be sent, the mail is not sending. When I run the same file without $_POST the mail() function works. Logs are not picking anything I have also added a "$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']" and still same outcome no delivery of mail.

CURL & Retrieval of response

```
if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
$full_name = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['e-mail'];
$cell = $_POST['cell'];

$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $source);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body = $xml->xpath('//soapBody')[0];
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE); 
      
$aStr = "";
$aStr = $array["AddRecordResponse"];
$aStr = trim($aStr);
if($aStr > 0){
$to = trim($email);
$subject = 'Added Record';
$message = 'Thank_you';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: no-reply@example.com';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Sent";
return true;
}else{
if($aStr <= 0 ){
$errTo = 'test@example.com';
$errSubject = 'Recorded did not go through';
$errMessage = 'Did not go through';
mail($errTo,$errSubject,$errMessage,$errHeaders);
echo "Error";
return false;
} 
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code that makes the curl request to the code you have give?

Comment: Curl request works as I mentioned that if I run the script without the $_POST it works and the mail is delivered.